# After the aliens had established first contact, where would it be most rational to put their embassy on Earth?

Tags: aliens, space-travel, geopolitics, firstcontact

Considering a scenario set in a relatively realistic space opera (Something Mass Effect'esque) where aliens had come to our planet at our current level of development, accepted us in some galactic union, and now want to build a spaceport and a small settlement that would be simultaneously their embassy-state on our planet and a point where trade and cultural exchange can occur between us and them (seeing as our attempts at spacefaring are pretty laughable for the foreseeable future, it's the only practical option). To safely land from orbit without the risk of endangering the local population with crashes, and simply by the fact that most likely standards of living of a spacefaring civilization would differ from our standards of living and they won't like it living in our buildings, they will need a whole settlement for that, not just a classical embassy building within our city.

So, where it would be most neutral, beneficial, and logical to put it on our planet(Considering that it will be the first, the largest, but eventually not the only spaceport on the planet, and we'll build further installations either jointly or all by ourselves)?

Taking into account that an interstellar spaceport can be a source of not only some fantastic things like alien technologies and knowledge, otherwordly alien materials, advanced alien consumer goods, and alien porn; but also potentially point of origin of some equally icky and dangerous stuff like alien diseases, alien drugs, alien pests, alien criminal activity, and alien porn.

The options I've considered so far:

- As near as possible to the UN headquarters, to ease and fasten up diplomatic and political relationship between human countries and the galactic union
- As near as possible to our largest and most developed city (Tokyo?), to ease trade and moving of goods
- At Cape Canaveral or Baikonur Cosmodrome, due to their historical significance to human space exploration efforts
- Somewhere in southern Africa, due to its historical significance as the birthplace of humanity.
- At a large floating platform constructed by the aliens on the equator in international waters (In either Pacific or Atlantic), for maximum neutrality and with no need to buy or lease actual territory from any of the governments which would make local populations unhappy; Easiest control on what exactly comes and leaves the spaceport; additional cool points for a cool floating high-tech city.
- No spaceports, just a space station in orbit around the planet with us needing to either get there by ourselves somehow or call for a space!taxi each time. Not very friendly from the aliens' side, plus it is safe to assume that such a space station will exist anyway in any of the other options as well because it's just far more convenient for taking in actual interstellar spaceships directly in orbit outside of the atmosphere.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115478/discussion-on-question-by-darth-biomech-after-the-aliens-had-established-first-c).

Answer (score 7):

Antarctica. Effectively it isn't under the jurisdiction of any country. Despite Australia's claims to a large fraction of the land mass. There isn't a native population to worry about, with room to establish a reasonable sized settlement. Besides global warming will be freeing additional tracts of Antarctica. If they can cross interstellar space, their orbit to surface spacecraft should be extremely reliable. So little worry about crashes.

The natives are a bit primitive. They are only human. There currently aren't extensive trade routes to Antarctica, but that will soon change. No nation's political sovereignty will be adversely impacted by an alien embassy at the Southern polar continent. Also, they won't be seen forming alliances with specific nations. Consider how most Western nations would react if the embassy was established in China or Siberia. Conversely, if it was in Western Europe, say, Paris or Venice.

If advanced alien technology included floating cities as part of their standard kit, then they wouldn't bother about choosing any specific location. An embassy could simply tour the planet on a regular basis passing over the majority of Earth's settlements. An air-taxi service could provide ready access.

Comment: So it's a point to the floating city I guess, Antarctica is absolutely out of question due to not only being an international natural preserve but also a really inconvenient place to get into orbit from.

Comment: @DarthBiomech Why would advanced bother about mere human international laws? It's inconvenient in terms of our primitive space technology. Possibly not to starfaring aliens. Also, you can avoid the Van Allen radiation belts by launching from the Poles. Yeah I like the floating city too. Much better than fixed real estate.

Answer (score 5):

**Completely depending on the aliens**

With the exception of your last option, the options are all completely based on human politics. I doubt the aliens will be very interested in human politics and will have other needs for their embassy. You don't discuss the location of you new house with your pets, maybe consider their feelings but they don't have much say in it.

Since you are talking about different alien races the first choice would probably be places were they feel comfortable. Assuming they don't need complete hazmat suits. The cold aquatic aliens will want to be close to the poles, warm aquatic, Mexico bay or the Mediterranean. Jungle aliens in Brazil or Africa, and so on. If they only can build one spaceport probably the most influential alien race determines the location.

Since they come to earth, for them it would be relatively easy to fly around the planet very fast. (Assuming they have unlimited free energy ,water and nuclear fusion is enough for that). So you can build many stations and don't have to be close to urban population.

There is a good chance we humans smell terrible or are very ugly and they don't want to be in our constant presence. Also walking around in a city might not be very nice for them. They will get huge amount of attention and mobs around them. But also the size and shape of our infrastructure might be horribly wrong for them. An elephant sized octopus like alien that uses suction for locomotion might not like our tarmac that much. Also a tiny alien will have a constant fear of being trampled in big cities. Let alone the amount of walking he would need to do to get somewhere.

Since no natural resources are of any importance to them and also assuming biological resources are not of any importance, the only reason they come here are for the humans. So maybe the art, politics or just curiosity.

**Answer:**
So my best bet would be that they build spaceports close to human urban population but far enough away not to be bothered by them and in the best suitable bio sphere for them.

Answer (score 3):

Paris.

With the option of raw resources off the table our visitors are interested in unique cultural artefacts and human intellectual capital.

[Statistica](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1064544/top-cities-museums-worldwide/) puts Paris as the city with the highest number of museums in the world at 297. It's also conveniently located for side jaunts to London and Amsterdam which sit in the top 10. And 6 of the top 10 [Museums](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/top-10/museum-galleries/) according to National Geographic are located in Western Europe.

Paris itself contains examples of every [architectural period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Paris) from the Middle Ages to the 21st century. As well as providing a reasonably central base to visit dozens of [World Heritage Cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Heritage_Site#Countries_with_15_or_more_sites).

One assumes that we're not actually expecting spaceships to touch down outside the embassy, just somewhere conveniently nearby. As such almost any major city is the same as another. If you've got an airport, you can upgrade that to a space port, especially with an interstellar power willing to help with the construction.

Answer (score 3):

### Western Central Africa

Lets think about what you want out of a space port.

**1. Lowest possible launch costs** (so on the equator) Getting to orbit is energetically expensive and will be part of the calculation any alien technology uses.

**2. Easy access to both land and sea for transportation.** (so near the coast) Transport times in space are so huge transport times on planet will be negligible by comparison so as long as they can access transportation its no problem.

**3. Lack of tectonics evens or extreme weather**. This eliminates a lot of locations, South America has mountains directly on the equator but they are also highly tectonically active. The Malay Archipelago offers connections to large trade hubs but is both tectonically active and prone to severe storms. That basically leaves Africa, and the western side of Africa is the most tectonically stable. Western central Africa is dead center on one of the most tectonically stable plates on the planet.

### based on this Gabon and the Republics of the Congo are your best choices.

It will be a huge boon to the countries and they have plenty of open land to build whatever is needed. Stabilizing the region politically is a problem for earthlings but will be greatly helped by the sudden influx of resources. It would not surprise me if the aliens looked at is a test, proof to us you can get your shit together. Moving the UN is easier than building a spaceport in a bad location, and this location will not show favoritism to any of the large superpowers and may even serve to give the UN a chance to reorganize.

Answer (score 2):

#### Spaceport location: Just outside of Darwin

[image]
I'm suggesting the Cox Peninsula 20km (as the bird flies) outside of Darwin, in north central Australia.

- We want minimal cost to launch so latitude 0 is the best bet. On the equator would be the best bet if this was all the mattered.
- However we also need security, customs, quarantine, port facilities, cargo ports. We need a developed country with stable government to host this.
- A nearby military base to be a last line of defence if hell breaks loose.
- Rockets can crash - so we need a big country with wide open spaces.
- We also need cargo and passenger seaport, international airport, and rail terminals nearby. All of these are within 30km.
- Booster rockets and capsules can do a water landing.
- And if all the rocket fuel goes up, we have the ocean available for fire fighting.
- Its warm weather stop the O-rings from failing - no more challenger explosions.
- Room for a massive runway for glider landings.
- Darwin international airport and the RAAF base can function as an alternate landing site. You can [land the space shuttle at either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAAF_Base_Darwin)
- The two other peninsulas in the picture may also be used, but cox was suggested as it looks like its not traditional Larrakia Aboriginal peoples land. They may be happy to negotiate the land use however - but we do want to keep it away from the city. There isn't good road access to the other peninsulas currently however.

#### Embassy location

This is a tricky one. Darwin is not a centrepiece of Earth culture, it's just a really convenient spaceport.

For day 0, I'd put this at the spaceport, as that's where it's needed most.

As things stabilise, I'd keep the one at the spaceport as a branch office, but move the real one to a more prominent location. It's up to the Aliens really. My suggestion would be The Hauge (Next to the international court or international peace palace), followed by New York (UN), followed by Beijing (China will be grumpy about not getting the spaceport - this may keep them happy), followed by Adelaide (Home of Australian space agency - and easiest 1-million+ city to get to from Darwin).

Answer (score 0):

The space station idea is not unfriendly. We've got the ISS, they could have their own station. This would be the safest location for aliens - no terrorists in space so far - but also the most convenient - no Westboro Baptist Church, no flat-earthers, no Qanon idiots to harass them.

If the aliens have a bone to pick with any nation on Earth they can go down and do it. If any nation wants to go up and talk to the aliens, they must either have a serious space program or have ties with a nation that does.

And if humans ever dial up the idiocy and try to attack the aliens, the aliens will be in the best position to either retaliate with tungsten rods of death, or move away the base with the least cost and hassle.

Also in space no one can force you to pay rent.

Comment: "If any nation wants to go up and talk to the aliens, they must either have a serious space program or have ties with a nation that does."
See, that's the part that is a problem. I don't think that out of the entirety of earth the nations that are able to launch manned spacecrafts should act as gatekeepers for everybody else less fortunate, and uneven "uplifting" of our planet would be the least optimal for both our integration into the galactic community and the political stability on the planet itself.